# How do I control the material to follow the topology correctly with subdivision?

Tags: materials, edges, topology

I don't know how to ask the questing the right way in one sentence, but I hope this description helps. I've been getting better in understanding topology but I'm still fairly new to blender. However, I understand subdev averages out the mesh (also material), but I have no Idea how to keep this material to maintain its curve on the picture below. I know it has something to do with the edge flow of my topology, but I have no idea how to fix it the right way. I circled part of the material I want to fix and the second pic is a better view of the topology. [image] [image]

Comment: Hello could you please show the reference object? Maybe also share your object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I ended up figuring it out little after I posted this. I'll leave the details in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out, it was so simple! I disolved the edges here [image: Removed Edges]

So I could have quads there again and then added an edge loop [image: Added Edge Loop]

Then redid the topology and bam! The material flows as it should[image: Topology with extra edge loop]